# Open Layers not displaying LineString added via addLayer on mobile

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a line string that needs to be displayed. It is a collection of GeoJSON data.

I have a problem where this works fine when opened in the browser, but when I open it in the mobile browser, the line that I am adding is not displayed.

Function that adds routeLayer

```
 const route = new LineString(breaks)

 route.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

 const routeFeature = new Feature({
      type: 'route',
      geometry: route,
 });

 const features = [routeFeature];

 routeFeature.setStyle(mainRouteStyle);
 const mainRouteVector = new VectorLayer({
       source: new VectorSource({
              features,
       }),
 });

 map.addLayer(mainRouteVector);
```

I couldn't find anywhere what is wrong, I don't have any errors. I am adding geo markers also with the same method and they are displayed. I also tried putting a simple line that connects 2 coordinates and it is also not shown when I add it later with addLayer but when I include that in layers when initializing the map, it is shown.

Keep in mind that on desktop browser it is working fine, but on mobile it has problems. Does anybody know what is the issue?

Comment: Double check the coordinates in `breaks`. A different locale can lead to this kind of behavior. Make sure there is no thousand separators and a dot for the decimals. If it is read from text, also parse it to be a number as OL doesn't always do this conversion automatically

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out this was not the issue with OpenLayers, I had targeting localhost to get the geojson data, which on mobile is obviously not localhost.